# create thumbnail from array of images

Tags: php

the app is created with codeigniter.
here is the code to create the thumbnail

```
private function _create_thumb($source){
    $path = './assets/upload/';
    $config = array(
        "image_library"=>"gd2",
        "source_image"=>$path.'/'.$source,
        "new_image"=>$path.'/'.$source,
        "maintain_ratio"=>TRUE,
        "create_thumb"=>TRUE,
        "thumb_marker"=>"_thumb",
        "width"=>"150",
        "height"=>"50"
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->image_lib->clear();
  }
```

and here is the code where the source images is located

```
if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("sl2_image")){
      $upload_data2 = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
      for($i=0; $i<count($upload_data2); $i++){
        $title = $this->input->post("sl2_title");
        $slider2[$title[$i]] = $upload_data2[$i]["file_name"];
        $this->_create_thumb($upload_data2[$i]["file_name"]);
      }

      if(count($slider2) > 0){
        $this->settings->save("slider2", serialize($slider2));
      }
    }
```

there is no problem in upload the images, the only one problem is only the last image have its thumbnail, for example i have array("1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"); only 3.jpg have its thumbnail. i believe there is something wrong with my code (that's why i asking it here :D )

Answer (score 0):

i answer my own question, here is updated

```
private function _create_thumb($source){
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$path = './assets/upload/';
$config = array(
    "image_library"=>"gd2",
    "source_image"=>$path.'/'.$source,
    "new_image"=>$path.'/'.$source,
    "maintain_ratio"=>TRUE,
    "create_thumb"=>TRUE,
    "thumb_marker"=>"_thumb",
    "width"=>"150",
    "height"=>"50"
);

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

}

initialize works better than putting the config in library load.